# Difference between two dates sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two dates in `sqlite`.
My times are at the format : `15h30`

When I try this :

```
select time(replace( FIRSTHOUR , 'h' , ':'))-time(replace (SECONDHOUR , 'h' , ':')) 
from table
```

I just get the result in hour like `2` if my dates are `15h30` and `17h40`

How can I get the result in hour and minute like `2:10`?

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlite> select strftime('%H:%M', 
                         strftime('%s', replace('17h40', 'h' , ':'))
                         - strftime('%s', replace ('15h30', 'h' , ':')),
                        'unixepoch');
02:10
sqlite>
```

So,

```
sqlite> select strftime('%H:%M', 
                         strftime('%s', replace(FIRSTHOUR, 'h' , ':'))
                         - strftime('%s', replace (SECONDHOUR, 'h' , ':')),
                        'unixepoch');
```

Alternatively,

```
sqlite> select strftime('%H:%M',
                         julianday(replace('17h40', 'h' , ':'))
                         - julianday(replace ('15h30', 'h' , ':'))
                         - 0.5);
02:10
sqlite>
```

So,

```
sqlite> select strftime('%H:%M',
                         julianday(replace(FIRSTHOUR, 'h' , ':'))
                         - julianday(replace (SECONDHOUR, 'h' , ':'))
                         - 0.5);
```